# Twig filter included template

Tags: php, twig, template-engine

I wanted to do something like this:

```
{{ include("tpl.html")|f }}
```

But that doesn't seem to work, it just printed `tpl.html` without any filtering, then I tried:

```
{% filter f %}
    {% include "tpl.html" %}
{% endfilter %}
```

And it worked. I just wonder, why can't I use shorter one? Do I misunderstand something?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you find a shorter way to do this? Or is using `{% filter %}` still the best way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry for being that long to come back :-)

The fact is that the `include` function writes on the template.

If you do :

```
{% set s = include('FuzHomeBundle:Default:test.html.twig') %}
```

Which is not supposed to display something, you'll get the content of the file output anyway, and the `s` variable will be set to `null`.

If you do instead :

```
{% filter upper %}
{% include 'FuzHomeBundle:Default:test.html.twig' %}
{% endfilter %}
```

or

```
{% filter upper %}
{{ include('FuzHomeBundle:Default:test.html.twig' }}
{% endfilter %}
```

The `filter` tag will compile some code that control output buffer.

Comment: No, I want to apply markdown filter no the whole output. Or does this sound stupid? Anyway, I want to say, that not escape, but any filter.

Answer (score 4):

To apply a filter on a section of code, you have to wrap it with the filter tag:

```
{% filter f %}
    ...
{% endfilter %}
```

What you were trying originally is to filter a variable which in twig is defined by the double parenthesis:

```
{{ variable name|filter }}
```

to read more check out the twig documentation on filters [here](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/filter.html)

Comment: `{{ }}` takes an expression, not necessarily a variable. In OP's case, a filtered function call is the expression, there is no mistake here.